# Вызов частичного представления с POST формой в другом представлении с другой моделью

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Всем привет, я создал по шаблону asp.net mvc приложение с системой identity.

Переопределив систему и добавив поля...

```
    // Фамилия пользователя
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    // Имя пользователя
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    // Отчество пользователя
    public string PatronymicName { get; set; }
    // Дата рождения, необходима для фильтрации игр по возрастной категории
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    // Номер телефона
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
```

...дописав в представление IndexViewModel nav вкладки...

```
         <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#mygames" data-toggle="tab">Моя коллекция игр</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#mydata" data-toggle="tab">Мои данные</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

...я заполняю данные контентом из частичного представления "_EditInfo":

```
            <div class="tab-pane" id="mydata">
                @Html.Partial("_EditInfo");
            </div>
```

### _EditInfo.cshtml

```
@model MyGameStore.Models.EditInfoViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditInfo", "Manage", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-signin form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SecondName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SecondName, new { @class = "form-control", value = Model.SecondName })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", value = Model.FirstName })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-xs-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PatronymicName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PatronymicName, new { @class = "form-control", value = Model.PatronymicName })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BirthDate, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BirthDate, new { @class = "form-control", value = Model.BirthDate })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-xs-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TelephoneNumber, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TelephoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control", value = Model.TelephoneNumber })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <br />
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Применить</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="reset"><i class="fa fa-repeat"></i> Сбросить</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Данное частичное представление всего лишь post-форма, которая позволяет изменять информацию о пользователе системы Identity.

Теперь в контроллере ManageController я соответственно имеют GET и POST действия с моделью EditInfoViewModel, которая содержит точно такие же поля, которые я переопределил в системе Identity.

### GET: EditInfo

```
public async Task<ActionResult> EditInfo()
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    if (user == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    var model = new EditInfoViewModel
    {
        SecondName = user.SecondName,
        FirstName = user.FirstName,
        PatronymicName = user.PatronymicName,
        BirthDate = user.BirthDate,
        TelephoneNumber = user.TelephoneNumber
    };

    return PartialView("_EditInfo", model);
}
```

### POST: EditInfo

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> EditInfo([Bind(Include = "SecondName,FirstName,PatronymicName,BirthDate,TelephoneNumber")] EditInfoViewModel model)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.Identity.Name);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return PartialView("_EditInfo", model);

        if (user != null)
        {
            user.SecondName = model.SecondName;
            user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
            user.PatronymicName = model.PatronymicName;
            user.BirthDate = model.BirthDate;
            user.TelephoneNumber = model.TelephoneNumber;

            var result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Что-то пошло не так");
        }
        else
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Пользователь не найден");

        return PartialView("_EditInfo", model);
    }
```

---

### Проблема при отладке

При рендеринге частичного представления                     `@Html.Partial("_EditInfo");` в представлении Index (Manage) возникает конфликт между двумя моделями "IndexViewModel" и "EditInfoViewModel":

---

> Элемент модели, переданный в словарь, имеет тип
>   "MyGameStore.Models.IndexViewModel", но для этого словаря требуется
>   элемент модели типа "MyGameStore.Models.EditInfoViewModel".

---

Comment: помогите пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1):

Два способа решения:

1. Либо использовать ту же модель IndexViewModel с точно такими же полями
2. Либо инициализировать поля модели EditInfoViewModel при вызове частичного представления **_EditInfo.cshtml**

   ```
       <div class="tab-pane" id="mydata">
           @Html.Partial("_EditInfo", new EditInfoViewModel
      {
          SecondName = Model.SecondName,
          FirstName = Model.FirstName,
          PatronymicName = Model.PatronymicName,
          BirthDate = Model.BirthDate,
          TelephoneNumber = Model.TelephoneNumber,
      });
       </div>
   ```